# wp-login.php just refreshes the form fields

Tags: login, reset

I've recently moved a customers blog from one server to another. On the surface everything seems to be working fine - the blog is running and you can view the entries with no issues.

The problem we're having is with the admin login page. When you enter your username and password it simply refreshes the page. No error messages or prompts are shown at all.

I've followed the tips on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

```
Cookies are enabled, tried via several browsers
Plugins folder has been renamed to plugins.old - aside from anything the only plugin within that folder was the default akismet one
Uploaded wp-login.php from a fresh download of 2.7.1
Reset password via command line mysql
URI is unchanged
Not using secure HTTPS
No errors about headers not being sent
```

I've checked error logs debug and there's nothing appearing related to WordPress.

...what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Update: sometimes this error appears:

Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to delete buffer zlib output compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a file ownership or permissions issue.

Try setting the permissions correctly as outlined here:

[Wordpress Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Glad to help :)